# Handling Json Array in VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net

I am getting data from some monitoring equipment which is returning what I believe is a Json (nested) array but the syntax is not quite right.

Below is a sample of what is being retuned. Its an array of UnixTimeMilliseconds and a value.

> [[1579617389000,132],[1579617399000,136],[1579617409000,139],[1579617419000,137]]

It could be up to 3000 sets of these numbers.

What I would like to do is dump them into an object of some sort an array so I am able to work with it e.g. translate the UnixTimeMilliseconds into datetime and do calculations.

Last thing I tried was:

```
Dim ListResultsArray As Directory()
ListResultsArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Directory())(emoncmsResponse)
```

and the error returned was:

> Could not create an instance of type System.IO.Directory. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].id', line 1, position 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method to convert the Arrays is to parse the JSON with [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm), iterate the inner arrays and produce a new class object, converting the array values to the desired type.

Create an object that can represent the array values:

```
<JsonArray>
Public Class NumbersItem
    Public Sub New(objTime As DateTimeOffset, objValue As Long)
        DetectionTime = objTime
        Value = objValue
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property DetectionTime As DateTimeOffset
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Long
End Class
```

Then parse the JSON and generate new class objects from each inner `JArray` object:

Since the first value in the Array represent an Unix DateTime expressed in milliseconds, we can use the [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds) method to convert it.

```
Dim numbers As New List(Of NumbersItem)()

Dim jsonArrays = JArray.Parse(json)
For Each array As JArray In jsonArrays.Children()
    numbers.Add(New NumbersItem(
        DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(CType(array.First, Long)),
        CType(array.Last, Long)))
Next
```

Now, you can inspect each `NumbersItem` class object in the list as usual.
The **`DetectionTime`** property is defined as a `DateTimeOffset` because the Unix time is expressed in UTC coordinates. You can use the `DateTimeOffset` methods to determine the local DateTime (`DateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime`) or perform other conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried JObject using NewtonSoft.json.Linq
Just create a JObject Array and parse Json

```
 Dim object As JObject()
 JObject.parse(object(index))
```